# Google Sheets Match function does not match properly

Tags: google-sheets

My idea is to have Names in column A which can repeat, its values in column B and than Unique values from column A in col. E and theirs sums in F. I have done that and it is simple.

Than, **and that is my problem**, I want to use conditional formatting for mark the same values in col. A and E for better look. Let's say green for odd lines and yellow for even

The simple sample is available here: [Test - Match names](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iealwk9fmOtetuea46s4AZb_x-cWcnV1eznq_-xbRhA/edit#gid=0)

I have used Custom formula `=ISODD(MATCH($A2,$E$2:$E$20))` and the second similar with `ISEVEN()` function for range A2:B20, but it only works with one letter names like 'A', 'B'... but no with "John", "Anna"...

In columns C are results from `MATCH($A2,$E$2:$E$20)` function. Similar for J.

Is there a bug in my sheet or is there something wrong with the `MATCH()` function?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The right is what I want and left what I am getting. But both left and right have the same "code"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a bug in my sheet or is there something wrong with the MATCH() function?

You are not using [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) properly for your situation. Where the `search_type` is not given it defaults to `1` which is to:

> assume that the range is sorted in ascending order and return the largest value less than or equal to search_key.

It uses a [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) method (for speed and efficiency) and this means that the result can be almost anything *when the range is not sorted*.

You might have better luck by inserting a third term of `,0`.

In other words, what works at present is not *single letters only* but *a range that is sorted ascending*.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not understand the `search_type` properly. You solved my problem.